# Removing duplicate rows from a data frame in R, keeping those with a smaller/larger value

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am trying to remove duplicate rows in an R data frame, but I want the condition that the row with a smaller or larger value (not bothered for the purpose of this question) in a certain column should be kept.

I can remove duplicate rows normally (from either side) like this:

```
df = data.frame( x = c(1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,1,2,3,3,4,5,6),
             y = c(rnorm(4),NA,rnorm(10)),
             id = c(rep(1,8), rep(2,7)))

splitID <- split(df , df$id)
lapply(splitID, function(x) x[!duplicated(x$x),] )
```

How can I condition the removal of duplicate rows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ave()` to return a logical index to subset your data.frame

```
idx = as.logical(ave(df$y, df$x, df$id, FUN=fun))
df[idx,, drop=FALSE]
```

Some possible `fun` include

```
fun1 = function(x)
    !is.na(x) & !duplicated(x) & (x == min(x, na.rm=TRUE))

fun2 = function(x) {
    res = logical(length(x))
    res[which.min(x)] = TRUE
    res
}
```

The dplyr version of this might be

```
df %>% group_by(x, id) %>% filter(fun2(y))
```

Answer (score 1):

We may need to `order` before applying the `duplicated`

```
lapply(splitID, function(x) x[!duplicated(x[order(x$x, x$y),]$x),] )
```

and for the reverse, i.e. keeping the larger values, `order` with `decreasing = TRUE`

Comment: When setting `decreasing = TRUE`, I get the row after the second duplicate removed.

Comment: @user3237820  Try with `lapply(splitID, function(x) x[!duplicated(x[order(x$x, x$y),]$x, fromLast = TRUE),] )`

Comment: Nope, this just removes the first duplicate from the bottom upwards, not the smallest value.

Comment: @user3237820  We ordered the 'x' and 'y' if you notice it

Comment: Running `lapply(splitID, function(i) i[with(i, order(x,y, decreasing=F)),] )`, then running `lapply(orderedSplit, function(x) x[!duplicated(x$x, fromLast = T),])` works, but not together (when I try at least!). Thanks for your help.